# How can i use Polymer project in my web view Android Application

Tags: javascript, android, webview, polymer-designer-tool

I want to use my polymer project in Android Web view but polymer element need a localHost server to run ?? so how can i run my Application without any localhost server in web view Android

Comment: This blog says you dont need a server: https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/07/use-polymer-apache-cordova/

Comment: they are  using coredova ...how to do it without using coredova

Answer (score 2, accepted):

polymer elements only supported in android 4.4.3+ version in web view,it doesn't support older version than 4.4.3+.